# 2D sub array problem

Tags: algorithms

Given a N*N 2D array in which each element could be between 1 to 100 I need to find subarray with most number of 1's in it,subarray with maximum 2's in it..and so on till for the maximum element of that array.How to tackle this algorithmic problem.

Answer (score 0):

The largest subarray with the most $1$'s in it is the whole array.  If it has to be smaller, just find the two edges you can delete that remove the minimum number of $1$'s.  It sounds like you may not have stated the problem correctly.

Comment: sorry,my mistake.actually i dont want to find maximum subarray but a subarray with maximum number of ones and so on

Comment: That seems to be the original question.  The original array has at least as many $1$'s as any subarray.  There must be something driving us to smaller subarrays.  Maybe you are looking for the subarray with the greatest fraction of $1$'s.  Stating the question carefully is very important.

Comment: yes i am looking for the subarray with greatest fraction of 1's